# How to deal with date fields from JSON in a GO struct

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have a JSON content, with some date fields like "resolutiondate" and "created" and "updated" as shown below

```
{
   "expand":"names,schema",
   "startAt":0,
   "maxResults":50,
   "total":1,
   "issues":[
      {
         "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
         "id":"id",
         "self":"https://url1",
         "key":"key1",
         "fields":{
            "summary":"Summary-1",
            "customfield_10406":null,
            "resolutiondate":"2021-06-10T10:07:35.000+0000",
            "created":"2021-06-10T10:05:24.000+0000",
            "description":"Description-1",
            ...
            ...
            ...
}
```

I am unmarshalling this JSON data into GO struct and saving the data in a excel sheet. Everything works as expected, the only issue is I'm defining the date fields as string datatypes in my GO struct, as below:

```
        Resolved           string `json:"resolutiondate,omitempty"`
        Created            string `json:"created,omitempty"`
```

Hence the final data saved in the excel file looks like:

[image]

But I want to save them as date datatype in the excel sheet, in a user defined format-mm/dd/yyyy. How can I effectively use the `time` package of Golang to achieve this ? Please help.

NOTE: I will be unable to share my complete code and the full JSON file.

Comment: What have you tried? Your code only shows bringing in strings, but you know that the `time` package is what you want. Have you tried it yourself? Can you show that code and what went wrong?

Comment: First, you want a custom `time.Time` type to unmarshal to. With that, you can then export time in any format: date-only; time-only etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For unmarshaling from custom format you need to create `time.Time` wrapper and implement `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    date, err := time.Parse(`"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-0700"`, string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    t.Time = date
    return
}
```

Now specify your time fields as `CustomTime`

```
Resolved           CustomTime `json:"resolutiondate,omitempty"`
Created            CustomTime `json:"created,omitempty"`
```

For writting into excel you need to provide more info about your implementation.

But example solution:

```golang
func (t *CustomTime) ExcelDate() string {
    return t.Format("01/02/2006")
}
```

Comment: don't bother stripping `"` from the bytes - just put the quotes directly in the format string e.g. `date, err := time.Parse(\`"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000+0000"\`, s)`

Comment: Is this formatting time into `mm/dd/yyyy` layout?

Comment: @nipuna, this *parses* time.  Its when you write out the excel file that you'd want to *format* that time.  Actually I think the entire date would go into the excel file, and instruct excel to display those dates in mm/dd/yyyy layout.

Comment: output in any format you like: `v.Resolved.Time.Format("01/02/2006")` ; `v.Created.Time.Format(time.RFC3339)`

Comment: @colm.anseo Thanks for pointing out. I will update example.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, wrap string as your own custom type, and make it implement the `Unmarshaler` interface:

```
type Unmarshaler interface {
    UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error
}
```

Then take time coming with JSON and parse it to `time.Time` and format with your custom layout `mm/dd/yyyy`.

```
type Date string

func (d *Date) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) error {
    dd, err := time.Parse(`"2006-01-02T15:04:05.000+0000"`, string(bytes))
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    *d = Date(dd.Format("01/02/2006"))

    return nil
}
```

Now you can use

```
Created            Date `json:"created,omitempty"`
```

inside your Go struct and unmarshal.

Run sample code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/F7ogxoU7nHV)

Comment: You're losing information here by coercing the time into a string with just date info. Better to unmarshal to a `time.Time` based type - and then *render* that time in any format you want after the fact.

Comment: @colm.anseo Yes, Correct. But I focused on the question's expectation and deliver the desired output in the Unmarshaler itself.

Comment: Why not do both? Preserve information & render in any format.